# drush 7 won't take a command without a site alias?

Tags: drush

I just installed drush 7.0-dev and with it all the composer and bash-completion goodness.  The installation went well and in a new shell it (drush 7) is now my default drush.

However it doesn't seem to want to take commands without aliases.  Is this really the new behavior or did I setup something wrong?

Here is a screenshot of a simple "drush dd files" command executed in my sites drupal root path.   I compare it to the drush 6 version which works fine without an alias.

Don't get me wrong I like aliases and all but this seems a bit draconian to force you to have to use them.

[image: I am in within a drupal site]

Comment: Was drush working before w/o aliases?  Are your sites in sites/default or somewhere else?

Comment: Yes drush 6.2.0 was and is working without aliases, as is obvious from the screenshot above.

Comment: Sorry, couldn't read screenshot on my tablet.  After you did the update, did you do a `drush cc drush`?  I have a server with a few versions of drush on it, and can't reproduce this.

Comment: No worries @MPD.  I had not done the 'drush cc drush' command before.  However I just tried it and it didn't help.  The strange thing is that a "drush st" works for the site without an alias. I tried pasting the output of it but stackexchange said it's 1900 characters too long :P.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify path or create sym link based on your server os.. Check Drush [Installation](https://drupal.org/node/1791676) instructions for more details..

It's documented in Github page to under [Install Manual](https://github.com/drush-ops/drush)..

> Configure your system to recognize where Drush resides. There are 3
>   options:
>
> Create a symbolic link to the Drush executable in a directory that is
>   already in your PATH, e.g.:
>
> $ ln -s /path/to/drush/drush /usr/bin/drush
>
> Explicitly add the Drush executable to the PATH variable which is
>   defined in the the shell configuration file called .profile,
>   .bash_profile, .bash_aliases, or .bashrc that is located in your home
>   folder, i.e.:
>
> export PATH="$PATH:/path/to/drush:/usr/local/bin"
>
> Your system will search path options from left to right until it finds
>   a result.
>
> Add an alias for drush (this method can also be handy if you want to
>   use 2 versions of Drush, for example Drush 5 or 6 (stable) for Drupal
>   7 development, and Drush 7 (master) for Drupal 8 development). To add
>   an alias to your Drush 7 executable, add this to you shell
>   configuration file (see list in previous option): $ alias
>   drush-master=/path/to/drush/drush
>
> For options 2 and 3 above, in order to apply your changes to your
>   current session, either log out and then log back in again, or re-load
>   your bash configuration file, i.e.:
>
> $ source .bashrc
>
> NOTE: If you do not follow this step, you will need to inconveniently
>   run Drush commands using the full path to the executable
>   "/path/to/drush/drush" or by navigating to /path/to/drush and running
>   "./drush". The -r or -l options will be required (see USAGE, below).
>
> Test that Drush is found by your system:
>
> $ which drush

Comment: It doesn't seem to be the problem, since `drush --version` returns 7.0-dev as version.

Comment: Right @kiamlaluno,  the executable being found is not the problem as is obvious from the drush --version output.